# C#: Enumerating SessionState keys in QuickWatch window

Tags: c#, debugging, session

While debugging in Visual Studio 2010, Is there a way to view the keys of a HttpSessionState in the QuickWatch window?

There must be a better method then exiting the debugging session, Coding a loop over the Session.Contents.Keys object, breakpointing and then stepping through the loop - just to see which keys are defined.

I suspect that i'm going about this in an entirely incorrect manner.  And hints or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpSessionState` is an `IEnumerable`, so as long as System.Core DLL is loaded in the process you're debugging, you can just evaluate `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast<object>(myHttpSessionState))` in the QuickWatch window. If the current code file has a `using System.Linq` statement, you can write a shorter expression: `myHttpSessionState.Cast<object>().ToArray()`

Comment: Fantastic, though I must be doing something incorrectly.  When I evaluate my HttpSessionState variable using the above statement, I receive the error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<object>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)' has some invalid argument.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot you need a Cast expression. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic.  The cast works perfectly - and the shorter Linq syntax is even better!

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing but this only gives me the session keys (which I can view anyway by expanding "Results View" after QuickWatch-ing the HttpSessionState). Is there a way to view the values at the same time or can they only be viewed individually (e.g. myHttpSessionState["mySessionKey"])?

Comment: @SteveChambers I don't see an easy way to do that, your best bet would be to write a method that takes in an HttpSessionState and converts it to a dictionary, and then calling that method from the QuickWatch window. A somewhat more complex solution would be to write your own [DebuggerTypeProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) for HttpSessionState and [put it in your autoexp.cs file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/10/02/5256045.aspx), the advantage of this approach being that it will work across different applications.

Comment: @OmerRaviv Perfect - thanks! I since raised this as a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033218/how-to-view-all-session-key-value-pairs-while-debugging). So if you'd care to copy your answer into there I'll gladly accept...