# How to view all Session key/value pairs when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, session

When debugging in Visual Studio (.Net MVC4), is it possible to see all [Controller.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) key/values at once? I can view all **keys** by typing `Session` into QuickWatch and expanding "Results View". E.g:

```
    Results View
    [0] "IsPlaced"  
    [1] "FromSLC"   
    [2] "PersonalId"    
    [3] "FullName"
```

Am aware that individual values can be inspected [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549424/how-to-view-session-variables-in-visual-studio-2008-debugger#answer-2549510) but haven't been able to get a list of **all keys and values** at the same time. Surely this must be possible, either in QuickWatch or the Immediate Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to do that, your best bet would be to write a method that takes in an HttpSessionState and converts it to a dictionary, and then calling that method from the QuickWatch window. A somewhat more complex solution would be to write your own [DebuggerTypeProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) for HttpSessionState and [put it in your autoexp.cs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/10/02/5256045.aspx) file, the advantage of this approach being that it will work across different applications and won't force you dirty up your solution with code that's only of use for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

**Idea A**
You could create a extension Method on the Session Object which prints its content the way you need it. Then call this Method in the immediate Window or add a watch to it.

**Idea B**
You could also create a custom visualizer which displays your Session Object like you intend.
There is a basis guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx

This also means adding code to your project but just like extension methods it will stay at a very defined place.

Comment: Thanks but I'm reluctant to alter the code for doing this as it is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Iam afraid there are not alternatives to adding some code. Whats wrong with having a class housing extension methods for debug purposes?

Comment: Nothing really in principle. But I'm working on an agile project with an aggressive timeline. All check-ins have to be associated with work items and unit tested. Would prefer to sidestep these overheads. [OK, you might argue such extensions would be of benefit to the whole team and hence worth it but you could argue that for a lot of things that would be of benefit but there isn't really time to do ;-)]

Comment: I loathe the all-to-frequent rule that code checkin's be associated with a work item. I feel that it stops folks from cleaning up code bit by bit. An alternative to get around the rule is to have an always-open work item called "Code Cleanup" and dump all non-item-driven refactoring under that.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding namespace:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

In the page where your session is created, add this:

```
Debug.Write(Session["your session value or text"]);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question.